# Reverting X and Y axes of a chart from C#

Tags: c#, excel, charts, office-interop

i'm creating a line chart from a dictionary values. Key is a long date time string and the value is a double value. So excel looks something like this:

9:22:39 AM  3.41

9:22:40 AM  3.91

9:22:41 AM  7.81

9:22:42 AM  2.44

9:22:43 AM  1.56

When I create the chart, time is on the Y axis and double values on the X axis. I want doubles to be the Y axis and time the X axis.

```
Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)newWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject chart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300,250);             
Excel.Chart chartPage = chart.Chart;

Excel.Range chartRange = newWorkSheet.get_Range("B1", "A" + row);
chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, Type.Missing);
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlLine;
chartPage.HasLegend = false;
```

In SetSourceData I tried both using columns and rows (the second argument), however it doesn't solve the problem. Any ideas how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the time is `B1:B5` and the double values is `A1:A5`, please try this code.

```
Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts =　(Excel.ChartObjects)newWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject chart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300,250);             
Excel.Chart chartPage = chart.Chart;

Excel.Range chartRange = newWorkSheet.get_Range("A1:A5");
chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, Type.Missing);
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlLine;
chartPage.HasLegend = false;

Series series = (Series)(chart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1));
series.XValues = newWorkSheet.get_Range("B1:B5");
```